# Proper url parsing using regex

Tags: php, regex

I have this regex from Wordpress. But I'm unable to properly adapt it to parse a URL. I want to parse only `http/https/ftp` links.

I tried to change the scheme part: `(http|https|ftp)+://`, but it's not working.

For the URL: `testhttp://google.com`

The match should be: `http://google.com`

Current match: `testhttp://google.com`

Thanks!

```
~
    ([\\s(<.,;:!?])                                        # 1: Leading whitespace, or punctuation
    (                                                      # 2: URL
        [\\w]{1,20}+://                                # Scheme and hier-part prefix
        (?=\S{1,2000}\s)                               # Limit to URLs less than about 2000 characters long
        [\\w\\x80-\\xff#%\\~/@\\[\\]*(+=&$-]*+         # Non-punctuation URL character
        (?:                                            # Unroll the Loop: Only allow puctuation URL character if followed by a non-punctuation URL character
            ['.,;:!?)]                            # Punctuation URL character
            [\\w\\x80-\\xff#%\\~/@\\[\\]*(+=&$-]++ # Non-punctuation URL character
        )*
    )
    (\)?)                                                  # 3: Trailing closing parenthesis (for parethesis balancing post processing)
~xS
```

Comment: Remove the `+`.

Comment: It's not clear what the current behavior is and what the expected one should be.

Comment: @revo current result with this regex is: `testhttp://google.com`. Should be `http://google.com`

Comment: Show a larger sample input.

Comment: Input is" `hello worldhttp://google.com`. Need to edit regex to match only `http://google.com`. Current match is `testhttp://google.com`

Comment: I tagged your question with PHP. If that's wrong, please tag the right language.

Comment: It's PHP language.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think the problem here is that your regex assumes the url is preceded by whitespace or punctuation as mentioned in the comment on the first line. If you want your regex to match an url within text without any separation, I'd remove that first line and change the scheme part as you tried, but without the + Quantifier in a Non-capturing group `(?:https?|ftp)://`.